# ASP.NET - child control in a Repeater doesn't get initialized in time

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater

I'm facing the following problem: I have an asp repeater who has a control as ItemTemplate. In codebehind, I assign a DataSource to the repeater:

```
...
this.ProductList = searchResult.Entry.ToList();
EntriesList.DataSource = this.ProductList;
...


void EntriesList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var productBlock = (ProductBlock)e.Item.FindControl("productBlock"); //Here I obtain the child, then assign the values from the datasource
    productBlock.ProductEntry = (Entry)e.Item.DataItem;
}
```

This is the aspx code of the childcontrol:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" CodeBehind="ProductBlock.ascx.cs" Inherits="EPiServer.Commerce.Sample.Templates.Sample.Units.CategoryDisplay.SharedModules.ProductBlock" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EPiServer.Commerce.Sample" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EPiServer.Commerce.Catalog.ContentTypes" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EPiServer.Core.Html" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EPiServer.Commerce.Catalog.ContentTypes" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Mediachase.Commerce.Catalog.Objects" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Mediachase.Commerce.Website.Helpers" %>
<%@ Register Src="StarButton.ascx" TagName="StarButton" TagPrefix="catalog" %>
<%@ Register Src="CommonButtons.ascx" TagName="CommonButtons" TagPrefix="catalog" %>

<li class="span3">
    <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-product">
        <catalog:StarButton runat="server" ID="StarButton" />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# ResolveUrl(StoreHelper.GetEntryUrl(ProductEntry)) %>'>
            <span class="product-img-holder">

                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1" AlternateText="" />
            </span>
        </asp:HyperLink>
        <div class="product-dsc">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# ResolveUrl(StoreHelper.GetEntryUrl(ProductEntry)) %>'  CssClass="product-name">
                <span><asp:Literal ID="HeadingLiteral" runat="server" /></span>
            </asp:HyperLink>
            <div class="tp-additional">
                <ul class="unstyled">
                    <li><strong>Marca:</strong>
                        <asp:Literal ID="BrandLiteral" runat="server" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <strong>Principio Activo:</strong>
                        <asp:Literal ID="ActiveIngredientLiteral" runat="server" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <strong>Patología:</strong>
                        <asp:Literal ID="PathologyLiteral" runat="server" />
                    </li>
                    <%--<li><strong>In Stock:</strong> <asp:Literal ID="InStock" runat="server"></asp:Literal></li>--%>
                    <li><strong>Código Nacional:</strong>
                        <span title="<%# ProductEntry.ID %>"><%# ProductEntry.ID %></span></li>
                    <%--<li><strong>Model:</strong>
                        <%# WebStringHelper.EncodeForWebString(GetModelNumber((EntryContentBase) Container.DataItem)) %></li>
                    <li><strong>List Price:</strong> <asp:Literal ID="ListPrice" runat="server" /></li>
                    <li><strong>Discount Pricing</strong> <asp:Literal ID="DiscountPricing" runat="server" /></li>
                    <li><strong>You Save:</strong> <asp:Literal ID="DiscountAmount" runat="server" /></li>--%>
                </ul>                              
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="False" ID="PromotionsHolder">
                    <%--<strong>Promotions:</strong><br />
                    <asp:Literal ID="Promotions" runat="server" />--%>                         
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="C_Product-ItemSelector">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="<%# ResolveUrl(StoreHelper.GetEntryUrl(ProductEntry)) %>"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i> Ver detalles</a> 
                    <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <catalog:CommonButtons runat="server" ID="CommonButtons" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

The code behind of this control just sets the values that should be given to the ProductEntry public property. In the debug, immediately after executing the EntriesList.DataSource = this.ProductList; line, the application raises a NullArgumentException, telling me that ProductEntry property from the child control is null.

However, if in the code behind of the child control of the repeater I do the following:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProductEntry = new Entry();
    }
```

Everything works as ProductEntry will not be null anymore.

This solution is rather ugly to me and I don't know why it happens and what is the best way to set a value for a child control inside a repeater. Can anyone enlighten me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You said Repeater control. If so, EntriesList_ItemDataBound's **EventArgs** should be **[RepeaterItemEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

Another problem is you need to filter **ItemType** inside **ItemDataBound**, because Header, Footer and others also fire **ItemDataBound** event.

```
protected void EntriesList_ItemDataBound(
   Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
      e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

      var productBlock = (ProductBlock)e.Item.FindControl("productBlock"); 
      productBlock.ProductEntry = (Entry)e.Item.DataItem;          
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Win your approach didn't work, child objects were still being created before and inited before I could assign them their values.

Hopefully, I've found the solution. Using the OnItemCreated event instead of the OnItemDatabound event solved my problem, as it was called when the child item was created, but before the Page_Init event of the child was called.

Thank you